# Black screen when try to lock screen

Tags: greeter, display, suspend

I don't know why I get a black screen when I try to lock the screen (<kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>), after a while it shows normal, the wallpaper and the option to unlock with my password, but I wonder why I get this black screen before, is does not happen in Ubuntu.

Another issue is than when my laptop is suspended for a long (very long) time or I don't shut it off in many days, when I try to wake it up I get a black screen for a while.

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: what GPU is used in this system? This could be a graphics driver issue with suspend.

Comment: For the issue you have when your laptop is suspended for many days, could it be because of the system being under memory pressure, the OOM (out of memory) killer runs and kills a critical process (resulting in the system freeze)?
Someone with more knowledge in this matter could have an answer.
I guess trying to configure the swappiness of your memory could help you, but as I said someone with more knowledge should give you a better answer.

Comment: Send a screenshot of your system information. Settings -> About

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but instead a black screen, it hanged for a while and displayed almost all the frame as a corrupted image, all except the text box and buttons. So I believe this is a GPU problem and Ubuntu may be using a different driver.

For me, the solution was:
1 - In the Applications menu, search for Software & Updates
2 - go to the Drivers tab
3 - I exchanged the proprietary driver (Nvidia 390) for the open source one (X server)
4 - Restarted and everything was faster without hiccups.

Check for this or look further for your GPU.

I don't know if this interferes with or causes the second problem, you'll have to further test it.