# Black, Unresponsive screen when Locking Desktop Session

Tags: greeter, graphics

When locking, the screen goes black and the system becomes unresponsive. I have looked carefully for available solutions and have tried them. None have worked for me. I am using Radeon R9 285/380 with the proprietary drivers. The X.ORG drivers do not support the resolution/type of my screen. Has anyone come up with a solution to this problem?

I am having the same problem as [Black screen when try to lock screen](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3504/black-screen-when-try-to-lock-screen)
and 
[Once locked, screen stays black and cannot be unlocked](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/586/once-locked-screen-stays-black-and-cannot-be-unlocked)

Update: I have manually installed AMD's proprietary driver and it did not fix the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue on a ryzen 7 computer with an NVIDIA card.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried maybe to switch the kernel version as it was suggested in this [answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/8838/6477)?

I've first tried (and succeeded) with a solution concerning driver update, that doesn't seem to work in your case, but maybe kernel switch could do the trick...